# What is the electric potential of a particle when it is initially released in a cyclotron?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

Lets assume a positively charged particle in a cyclotron. When released it will move to a dee. Hence, does it move to an area of higher electric potential or lower electric potential?

In my understanding, since it is a positively charged particle and will move to the negative dee, it will have a lower electric potential. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The particle orbiting in a cyclotron is accelerated by (an alternating) voltage each time it crosses the gap between the “dees”. Its initial potential energy would be equal to the kinetic energy gained on its first crossing of the gap.  (The potential decreases in crossing the gap.)

Comment: Thanks! So, with respect to the beginning, it is at a lower potential?